# wordpress admin ajax not working, returning entire html of page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, admin-ajax

I have following code in my `functions.php` file.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'broadcast-ajax-request', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/global.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'broadcast-ajax-request', 'ajaxadmin', array('ajaxurl'=> admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_my_option', 'get_my_option' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_my_option', 'get_my_option' );

function get_my_option()
{
    print_r($_POST); exit;
}
```

And following code in `global.js`.

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
  jQuery("#submit_btn").click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxadmin.ajaxurl,
        data: {'action':'get_my_option', 'test':'test'},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response){
        }
    });
  });
});
```

But it always returning `html` code in response.

Comment: use `dataType: "json",` if you want json.

Comment: tried that already, same issue @ParthTrivedi

Comment: what do you want in response?

Comment: whatever i write in this function `get_my_option`

Answer (score 0):

Script enqueues and localizations need to take place in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook:

```
function so_34632421_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'broadcast-ajax-request', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/global.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'broadcast-ajax-request', 'ajaxadmin', array('ajaxurl'=> admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_34632421_enqueue_scripts');
```

Read more [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script#Notes).

Comment: tried that, but still same thing. returning html code

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a late reply, but hopefully it can help someone.

When you localize the Wordpress admin ajax url, you are setting a variable that is inserted by Wordpress into your page as such:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
var bookingajax = {"ajax_url":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
```

When using admin-ajax.php is the backend of your plugin, the adminajax variable is set as such:

```
var ajaxurl = '/gss/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
```

The best way to check if the ajax url has been localized is to print to the console the variable you have set.

In my example, I have set localized my admin-ajax.php using bookingajax.

if you print this variable to with console.log(bookingajax), you will see that this is now stored in a javascript object.

**And here is the solution!**

In your example above, you are still using the adminajax variable. You will need to add the underscore that is set in the variable stored in the frontend as such.

```
var ajaxurl = bookingajax.ajax_url;

jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {'action':'get_my_option', 'test':'test'},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response){
        }
    });
```